Merging two dataframes of different lenght by two columns that are in both dataframes, but exist multiple times in one dataframe
I have two dataframes. One main dataframe and one supplementary dataframe.
Both of those dataframes contain the columns "year" and "density". "year" is only present as six different values (2010, 2012, 2014, 2017, 2020, 2023). These are the years in which data has been collected.
"density" is only present in five different values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
My supplementary dataframe is 30 rows long, so each combination of "year" and "density" is present exactly once. the supplementary dataframe has a third column called "drought", which has a unique value for all 30 of the combinations that is not yet in my main dataframe.
I now want that unique value for "drought" in my main dataframe. However, my main dataframe is longer and has each combination of "density" and "year" multiple times.
How can i merge these dataframes so that i have the correct value for "drought" in each row of my main dataframe corresponding to the 30 combinations of "year" and "density"?
I tried a simple left_join:
main_df <- main_df |> 
  left_join(supp_df, by = c("year", "density"))

When i do this, no new column named "drought" appears in my main dataframe.

You will need to share a minimal reproducible example of your problem, including code and data. Also, it is good to properly format your code using back ticks ( ) so that it is easier to read.

If your data is as you described textually , then what you tried should have worked. You will need to investigate where your description falls short so as to invalidate this working example
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

(main_table <- expand_grid(
  year = c(2001, 2002),
  density = c(1, 2)
) |>
  sample_n(size = 10, replace = TRUE) |>
  mutate(
    other_facts_on_main_table = runif(10)
  ))

(supp_table <- expand_grid(
  year = c(2001, 2002),
  density = c(1, 2))|>
    mutate(
      drought = runif(4)
    ))

(fin_table <- left_join(main_table,
                       supp_table,
                       by = join_by(year, density)))

